# How do we describe the objects or systems like an "organic meal"?

Tags: language, properties, objects

For a meal to be organic all the ingredients need to be organic, if one item isn't then technically the meal isn't organic. The same could be said about a vegan meal. I'm looking for a word to describe this phenomenon.

What is a word to describe a system where the individual parts have an attribute (organic, vegan) and only when each part is 100% to have that attribute then the new product also has that attribute, if 0.1% doesn't have that attribute then product also fails to have that attribute.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a term in linguistics, but in mathematics they call it a [hereditary property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditary_property) of an object when it is "inherited by all of its subobjects, where the meaning of subobject depends on the context". So if you interpret "subobject" as ingredient then the property of being organic is hereditary. When such reasoning is erroneously applied to a *non*-hereditary property they call it the [fallacy of division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_division) in logic.

Comment: The odds of any real macroscopic object not containing some microscopic quantity of substances ubiquitous in its environment (or the chemicals formed from those substances after cooking, manufacturing, etc) are indistinguishable from zero, so this might just be an [idealization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idealization_(philosophy_of_science)) if we're talking about the characteristics of real things, as opposed to trying to name the characteristic of the particular idealization to which the real things are being compared.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at [WP's article on properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_(philosophy)) and the [SEP's article on properties](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/properties/#KindProp) and either without any luck. In the [IEP's article on properties](https://iep.utm.edu/properties/#SH7f) we seem to come close with 'indiscriminantly necessary properties', but that doesn't quite seem to apply:

> Property instantiated by every particular

For instance, all bananas have the property of having a banana genome is indiscriminantly necessary. But bread being organic wouldn't be indiscriminant as there are obviously non-organic instances. This is also true in computer science and object-oriented programing when you instantiate an object from a class. Any class OrganicBread that has the property const OrganicBread.HasAllOrganicIngredients = true would be necessarily true if one were to instantiate the class. But in the case of the bread in the philosophical sense, it stands to reason it would be a conditionally necessary property with the condition being "all ingredients are organic". Interestingly, the ingredients would require the indiscriminately necessary property of being organic in the context of being elements of a composition.

So, there you have it and can put those two ideas and abstract to the general case together for some word-fun: **it is a "conditionally necessary property of composition necessary by indiscriminately necessary properties of parts"**. For instance, this would apply to the [one-drop rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-drop_rule) which is obviously a metaphorical extension of the broader notions of purity and contamination. Any carafe of water is pure if and only if any volume of water added to the carafe is pure. Of course, the label I created is idiosyncratic, and not canonical, so there might yet be an accepted term among professional metaphysicians. (There are a number of papers on [metaphysical taxonomies of properties such as this one (JSTOR)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2254537), and you might find simpler jargon ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts since I posted this question, and thanks for all the input. This system is one based on heritage / lineage. These properties are given down to "children" thinking in terms of evolution or biology. To coin a term I think it's simply a:

> "familial system"

An important thing to note here is the "generationality" of the attributed properties is flexible. You could have a system where every generation needs to maintain continuity or you could have continuity be broken for many generations and then culminate in a new attribute forming and starting a new "familial system".

An example of a strict continuity or generational lineage is in the case of an organic or vegan meal, thinking in terms of the supply chain as successive generations, everything from the salad dressing, to the cattle feed (non vegan), to the soil within the farms needs to maintain strict continuity for successive generations of products to be "Organic".

An example of a loose continuity there's the idea or philosophy of "union made" goods. This concept doesn't adhere to a strict continuity. The "Union made" aspect of a good might just be final assembly and not the whole supply chain, fabic, thread, needles could have been sourced from different shops that were not organized by union labor.

Creative commons and software licencing, are other good examples of these kinds of systems where the word "generation" is replaced with "iteration".